# Spivak, Ch. 15, Problem 25. Interpretation of proof that $|\sin{x}-\sin{y}|<|x-y|$ for all numbers $x\neq y$.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification

> 25. Prove that $|\sin{x}-\sin{y}|<|x-y|$ for all numbers $x\neq y$.

Let $x\neq y$. The Mean Value Theorem tells us that there is some $c\in (x,y)$ such that

$$\frac{\sin{x}-\sin{y}}{x-y}=\sin'(c)=\cos(c)$$

$$\left | \frac{\sin{x}-\sin{y}}{x-y} \right | = | \cos{c}| \leq 1$$

$$|\sin{x}-\sin{y}|\leq |x-y|$$

Equality holds if $|\cos{c}|=1$, which means $c=k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**The claim in the problem statement is essentially that it never occurs that we have $x\neq y$ and a $c\in (x,y)$ from the MVT such that $|\cos{c}|=1$, correct?**

To prove this we take two numbers $x<y$, and a third number $z\in (x,y)$ chosen such that there is no number of form $\pi k\in (x,z)$.

Then

$$|\sin{y}-\sin{x}|=|\sin{y}-\sin{z}+\sin{z}-\sin{x}|$$

$$=|(y-z)\cos{c_1}+(z-x)\cos{c_2}|\tag{1}$$

where $c_1\in(z,y)$ with $|\cos{c_1}|\leq 1$, and $c_2\in (x,z)$, so $c_2\neq k\pi \implies |\cos{c_2}|<1$.

Therefore

$$|\sin{y}-\sin{x}|<|(y-z)\cdot 1 +(z-x)\cdot 1| \tag{2}$$
$$= |y-x|$$

Comment: There is no law of inequality saying that if $|b| < b'$ and $|d|<d'$ then $|ab+cd| < |ab'+cd'|$. If you play around with numbers I'm sure you can find a counterexample.

Comment: I don't see why $|au+bv|<|a+b|$ when $|u|<1$ and $|v|\le 1$. Take $a=2$, $u=-1/2$, $b=-2$, $v=1$.

Comment: The proof is from Spivak or your own? In the latter case, what you get is that the MVT is not the right tool to prove the strict inequality.

Comment: Spivak uses the same argument. The only difference is that from the "Then" onwards I put in the absolute value signs

Comment: @egreg the mistake you are referring to is from $(1)$ to $(2)$, correct?

Comment: @evianpring Yes, you cannot do that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are correct. Just clean up your last line by making it rigorous:

Therefore

$$\vert \sin{y}-\sin{x}\vert = \vert(y-z)\cos{c_1}+(z-x)\cos{c_2}\vert $$

$$ \leq \vert y-z \vert\ \vert \cos{c_1}\vert\ + \vert z-x \vert\ \vert \cos{c_2}\vert $$

$$ < \vert y-z \vert + \vert z-x \vert$$

$$ = (y-z) + (z-x)\quad \text{ because } x<z<y $$

$$ = y-x = \vert y - x\vert. $$

Answer (score 5):

Note that, for $x\ne y$
$$|\sin x- \sin y |=|2\cos\frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2 |\le 
2|\sin\frac{x-y}2 |<|x-y|$$

Comment: Best 1-liner this month.

Comment: How do we know that $\sin{\frac{x-y}{2}}\geq \cos{\frac{x+y}{2}}$?

Comment: @evianpring - you only need to know $|\cos t|\le 1$

Comment: Where does the last inequality come from?

Comment: With regard to the last inequality, don't we have $|2\sin{\frac{x-y}{2}}|=\left | \sin{\frac{x-y}{2}}-\sin{\frac{y-x}{2}} \right | \leq|x-y|$?

Comment: @evianpring . For all real non-$0$ $z$ we have $|\sin z|<|z|.$ In particular, when $0\ne z=\frac {x-y}{2}.$

Comment: That seems pretty clever, though I must say, it seems like an important choice which steps to leave out right, ie which ones to leave implicit. $|\sin{x}-\sin{y}|<|x-y|$ is a also a proof of $|\sin{x}-\sin{y}|<|x-y|$, no?

Answer (score 3):

Let $x<y$. Without loss of generality assume that
$\sin x\le \sin y$. The
$$
|\sin y- \sin x|=\sin y- \sin x=\int_x^y \cos t\,dt=\\
(y-x)-\int_x^y (1-\cos t)\,dt= \\
=
(y-x)-\frac{1}{2}\int_x^y \sin^2 (t/2)\,dt.
$$
It suffices to show that $\int_x^y \sin^2 (t/2)\,dt>0,$ whenever $y>x$.

But for the continuous function is nonnegative, $\sin^2 (t/2)\ge 0$, for all $t$, and not identically zero in any interval. Hence $\int_x^y \sin^2 (t/2)\,dt>0$, whenever $y>x$.

Comment: If $\sin x\geq \sin y$ then the first equation seems to be backwards.

Comment: I believe that is a typo. It should be $\sin{y}\leq \sin{x}$. Also, I believe that in the term $\frac{1}{2}\int_x^y \sin^2{t/2}dt$, the $1/2$ should be a $2$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

For $r>0$ and $S\subset \Bbb R,$ say that $S$ is $r$-discrete iff $|x-y|\ge r$ whenever $x,y$ are unequal members of S.

Suppose $r>0$ and $S$ is an $r$-discrete subset of $\Bbb R$. Exercise: If $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is differentiable and if $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R\setminus S$ then $f$ is strictly increasing. (Hint: If $x<y$ there are only finitely many members of $ (x,y)\cap S$).

(1). Let $f(x)=x-\sin x.$ Then $f'(x)=1-\cos x.$ Let $S=\{2n\pi: n\in\Bbb Z\}.$ Now $[x\ne y\land \frac {\sin x-\sin y}{x-y}=1]\implies [x\ne y\land f(x)=f(y)],$ which is impossible as $f$ is strictly increasing.

(2). Let $f(x)=x+\sin x.$ Then $f'(x)=1+\cos x.$ Let $S=\{(2n+1)\pi: n\in\Bbb Z\}.$ Now $[x\ne y\land \frac {\sin x -\sin y}{x-y}=-1]\implies [x\ne y\land f(x)=f(y)],$ which is impossible as $f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: What does $(x,y) \cap S$ mean?

Comment: @evianpring . $(x,y)=\{z: x<z<y\}$ is the open real interval between $x$ and $y$.... ...$(x,y)\cap S$ is the set of all the members of $S$ that are members of $(x,y)$.